# Passing multiple file patterns to grep

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have a sequence of search patterns stored in a bash array (`ptrn`), which I want to pass to a `grep` command.  How can I do it?

```
  ptrn=("FN" "DS")
  for fl in "$@"; do  # loop through number of files
    if [[ -f "$fl" ]]; then
      printf '\n%s%s%s\n\n' "$mgn" "==>  $flnm  <==" "$rst"
      grep --color "$ptrn" "$flnm"
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Use ${ptrn[@]}  for grepping

Comment: Does not seem to be enough because I get `grep: DS: No such file or directory`.  It is thinking that the pattern is a file.

Comment: Try "${ptrn[@]}" instead for grep

Comment: Same problem.  Does not recognise as a search pattern.

Comment: How about grep "${ptrn[0]}\|${ptrn[-1]}" . First and last.

Comment: Have done this `pa=$(printf '%s\|' "${ptrn[@]}")` followed by `grep --color -E "$pa" "$flnm"`.  But nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- Standards-compliant way: Join the patterns with newline and provide it as single argument:

  ```
  grep -e "$(printf "%s\n" "${ptrn[@]}")" ...
  ```

  (This feature is specified by [the POSIX standard](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/grep.1posix.html): "The *pattern_list*'s
  value shall consist of one  or  more  patterns  separated  by  <newline>  characters ...")
- Non-standard, but still safe way: When using a shell with arrays, like, e.g., bash, build an array of arguments to `grep`:

  ```
  args=()
  for p in "${ptrn[@]}"
  do
     args+=(-e "$p")
  done
  grep "${args[@]}" ...
  ```

  This is safe from field-splitting and globbing, and in general is [how command lines should be built from variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/70524).

Comment: I would that say that storing in a single string, for instance:  `mptrn=$( printf -- ' -e %s' "${ptrn[@]}" ) ; grep "$mptrn" ..`  introduces certain problems.

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about giving the patterns to `grep` through a sub-shell, e.g.:

```
grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "${ptrn[@]}") FILE...
```

Comment: You mean `bash` specific process substitution syntax `<(...)` ... That is smart, processing array elements into newlines and reading by `grep` as a file of patterns ... If, however, you quote the expansion of the array i.e. `<(printf "%s\n" "${ptrn[@]}")` , then each element will be passed as a single token, which might be desirable to preserve exact spaces ... +1

Comment: Even without process substitution, you could do `printf "%s\n" "${ptrn[@]}" | grep -f - FILE` (of course, assumes you are not grepping stdin itself)

Comment: I confirm that quoting the expansion of the array is required.

Answer (score 2):

If your patterns/words stored as array elements are guaranteed to not have spaces or non-escaped shell special characters in them, then you can use `bash`'s parameter expansion to pass the array elements to `grep` as separate individual patterns e.g. `-e FN -e DS ...` like so:

```bash
ptrn=("FN" "DS")

# Prepend "-e" to each array element
ptrn2="${ptrn[@]/#/-e }"

# Don't quote "$ptrn2" or it will be passed as a single token and wouldn't work.
grep --color $ptrn2 file
```

Or if they might contain non-escaped shell special characters, you can build the regular expressions around `|`(*or*) (*splitting on all spaces as well but not failing*) and use it with something like:

```bash
ptrn=("FN" "DS")

# Translate spaces " " single or multiple including spaces between words in a single array element into "|".
ptrn2="$(echo ${ptrn[@]} | tr " " "|")"

# -E enables extended regular expressions ... needed for this to work.
grep --color -E "$ptrn2" file
```

Or to preserve exact spaces inside each regular expression pattern passing each array element as an individual token and building an extended regular expression of them using the `|`(*logical or*), you can do something like this:

```bash
ptrn=("FN" "DS")

# Append "|" to each array element.
ptrn2="$(printf '%s|' "${ptrn[@]}")"

# Delete the last character i.e. the extra "|".
ptrn2="${ptrn2::-1}"

# -E enables extended regular expressions ... needed for this to work.
grep --color -E "$ptrn2" file
```

Comment: I want the search pattern to be any allowable regex, with exact strings only being a special case.  This means that the demand of not to have spaces in the patterns is too restrictive.

Comment: Would that not be the same as `pa=$(printf '%s\|' "${ptrn[@]}")`?

Comment: Something specific to bash must be going on because `grep -E "## FN|## DS" ./firefly.rc` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Got things to work by removing the first `"|"`.  Therefore `pa=$(printf '|%s' "${ptrn[@]}") ; pa="${pa:1}"`.

Comment: @Backy Well done :-) ... I added extra info to the answer.

Comment: There also exists the capability of using the `-e` flag multiple times up to the desired number of search patterns.

Comment: How could I possibly handle the supply of multiple `-e PATTERN` expressions ?

Comment: @Backy Other than the example in my answer. .. IIRC `-e` can also be passed as an option with `-f` to read patterns from file

Comment: In a loop I could do  `ptrn[$i]="-e ${ptrn[$i]}"`.  But I wonder whether blanks in the array element could be misinterpreted, as the `-e` would not be passed separately to the pattern.